# Using vs Try/Catch/End try (Exit Function)

Tags: sqlite, try-catch, using

We have found out during our SQLite implementation that SQLite databases will get locked without fully disposing any Sqlite Commands and Sqlite DataReaders.
As as result we are modifying our Try..Catch..End Try with Using...End Using.
Any datareaders within the Using..End Using are disposed after closing.
Commands are disposed with the End Using.

However many of our Try..Catch..End Try includes the "Exit Function" within the Catch portion.

Is there a way within the Using..End Using to Catch an exception, deal with it, exit the function, while still being able to dispose with the command like End Using does?

We are using a combination of c# and vb.net within our application/libraries

Comment: Thanx CL. The documentation says: " END USING => Required. Terminates the definition of the Using block and disposes of all the resources that it controls." So in our case if using the Try..Catch..End Try and exiting the Function within the Catch..how does it ever get to the END USING? Whether you put the Using..End Using outside the Try..Catch..End Try OR within the Try..Catch..End Try, if an exception occurs it will move to Catch where the exception is handled and then the Exit Function occurs...it still never gets to END USING.

Comment: Removed Exit Function within the Catch portion of Try..Catch..End Try. Don't need this. Over site on our end.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) says that

> the `Using` block guarantees disposal of the resources, no matter how you exit the block.